# Lebesgue integral of $x \to \cos(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

why we have $\cos(x) \notin L^1(\mathbb{R})$?
i.e, why 
$$
\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |\cos(x)| dx 
$$
is not finite?

Thank you in advance to the help

Comment: The integrand function is non-negative and larger than $\frac{1}{2}$ at each point of $2\pi\mathbb{Z}+(-\pi/3,\pi/3)$.

Comment: @VanillaThunder That logic is not sufficient by itself. Consider the set $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} [k, k+2^{-k}]$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}$, which is the union of infinite disjoint intervals. If we take the indicator function on this set (i.e.the function that is $1$ on the set and $0$ elsewhere), we find that its integral over $\mathbb{R}$ is equal to $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k} = 1$.

Comment: @VanillaThunder Or, take a function equal to $2^{-k}$ on $[k, k+1)$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}$, you get the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want a formal proof. Note that $I_k = \int_{\pi k-\pi/2}^{\pi k+\pi/2} \lvert \cos(x)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x = 2$ for any given $k$. Your integral is therefore bounded below by $\sum_{k=0}^n I_k = 2(n+1)$ for any $n$. Then let $n$ go to infinity to see that the integral cannot be finite.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\displaystyle\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} |\cos(x)| dx =2
$$
$$
\displaystyle\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} |\cos(x)| dx =2
$$
$$
\displaystyle\int_{0}^{N} |\cos(x)| dx \geq \lfloor 2N/\pi \rfloor
$$

so your integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ doesn't converge.